# Convert Stardict dictionary file to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I'm building a online dictionary website and I've been encountering some problem that hopefully you guys could help me.
I download the dicts file here http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/
How do I convert those dicts to Database?

Answer (score 3):

The stardict tools come with `stardict_stardict2txt` and `stardict_tabfile2sql`.
Use them like this:

`stardict_stardict2txt some-input.ifo some-output.txt

stardict_tabfile2sql some-output.txt`

You'll get some-output.txt.sql